# Applying Filter to outlook folder VBA

Tags: vba, filter, outlook

I am struggling with a piece of my code.

I am filtering a folder in outlook to restrict the subject and the received time.

The filter works perfectly if I am only interested in a day greater than another day. 
I.e -

```
datevalue = Format(Sheet1.Range("c" & reloop).Value - 1, "DDDDD HH:NN")
```

Local view 30/07/2017 - value on spreadsheet is 30/07/2017 00:00:00

When I try to filter greater than day and time it breaks down and returns all items in folder.

I am setting the datevalue below

```
datevalue = Format(Sheet1.Range("L" & reloop).Value, "DDDDD HH:NN")
```

This in the locals window looks like 31/07/2017 07:00:00. value on spreadsheet is 31/07/2017 07:00:00

The full code I am using is as below for the filter

```
    strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " = '" & FilterValue & "' And " & Chr(34) & _
        "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & Chr(34) & " > ' & " & datevalue & " & '"
```

Is this simply a formatting issue when declaring the datevalue?

Comment: Can you try the other formating like "DD/MM/YYYY"

Comment: I need the time to be considered if I change it from "ddddd hh:nn" to "dd/mm/yyyy" will it remove the time stamp

Comment: Yes, it will remove the timestamp from it. It will be much more efficient if you use the same formatting for all the date to avoid any mismatch error

Comment: For more date format,  you can do Trial and error in excel cell using Custom formating and try different combinations and you can use the same formating style in your vba code. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`> ' &` is a part of the filter string.

Comment: Does it need to be & > "  ' & "

Comment: Most likely & " > '" & datevalue & "' "